# Bash: source file executes code inside strings

Tags: json, string, bash, variables

***(Premise:)***

Hi, i'm trying to read a JSON file whose content has to be copied inside a variable in a file that i'm going to need later, according to google the only way to do this is by using `source`. I need to avoid command execution during the sourcing tho, and, being a JSON file, all those quotes are causing me a bit of a headache.

Because of this I need to be sure that each and every one of them is escaped to be treated as plain text. I tried using `sed` command like this:

```
sed -e "s/'/\\\'/g" -e 's/"/\\"/g'
```

Checking again in the file i can see that every single quote has been escaped apart from the outer ones

```
ex: {{"foo":"bar"},{"bar":"foo}} -> VAR='{{\"foo\":\"bar\"}{\"bar\":\"foo\"}}'
```

Somehow when i execute the sourcing i get a lot of errors about commands and directories not existing.

***(Question:)***

Do you have any idea of what's going on? Is this even a viable solution to get to my goal? Is there any better way? If what i'm asking is not possible, is there any other way to use a file as a string variable store?

***(Goal generic desired behaviour:)***

- read json
- create conf file
- attach json content to variable declaration string (`"VAR=$(readthejson)"`)
- attach variable declaration string to conf file
- source conf file
- use var as a string

***(Trial specific desired behaviour:)***

```
a=$( sed -e "s/'/\\\'/g" -e 's/"/\\"/g' myjson.json )
echo "LOCK='$a'"  >> file
```

The lines above successfully fill my `file` with json content and escapes all quotes
*(example from a package-lock.json file:)*

```
  LOCK='{
  \"name\": \"Undecided\",
  \"version\": \"0.0.1\",
  \"lockfileVersion\": 2,
  \"requires\": true,
  \"packages\": {
    \"\": {
      \"version\": \"0.0.1\",
      \"dependencies\": {
        \"@capacitor/android\": \"3.1.2\",
        \"@capacitor/app\": \"1.0.2\",
        \"@capacitor/core\": \"3.1.2\",
        \"@capacitor/haptics\": \"1.0.2\",
  ...
```

At this point i would expect that sourcing `file` would result in my strings being loaded in my script and being usable like so:

```
source file
echo "$LOCK"
```

*output:*

```
{
  "name": "Undecided",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "@capacitor/android": "3.1.2",
        "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
        "@capacitor/core": "3.1.2",
        "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.2",
```

***(Actual behaviour:)***

The script escapes everything as needed. Though when i source it it outputs this:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
file: line 2128: },: command not found
file: line 2129: "node_modules/@hapi/bourne":: No such file or directory
file: line 2130: "version":: command not found
file: line 2131: "resolved":: command not found
file: line 2132: "integrity":: command not found
file: line 2133: "deprecated":: command not found
file: line 2134: },: command not found
file: line 2135: "node_modules/@hapi/hoek":: No such file or directory
file: line 2136: "version":: command not found
file: line 2137: "resolved":: command not found
file: line 2138: "integrity":: command not found
file: line 2139: "deprecated":: command not found
file: line 2140: },: command not found
file: line 2141: "node_modules/@hapi/joi":: No such file or directory
file: line 2142: "version":: command not found
file: line 2143: "resolved":: command not found
file: line 2144: "integrity":: command not found
file: line 2145: "deprecated":: command not found
file: line 2146: "dependencies":: command not found
file: line 2147: "@hapi/address":: No such file or directory
file: line 2148: "@hapi/bourne":: No such file or directory
file: line 2149: "@hapi/hoek":: No such file or directory
file: line 2150: "@hapi/topo":: No such file or directory
file: line 2151: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
file: line 2151: `      }'
```

It looks like it's ignoring backslashes, or that they get swapped with non escaped quotes and then sourced.
I mean, i would expect that `echo "\"lorem\"\"ipsum\""` result in `"lorem""ipsum"`, not in a
`lorem command not found`
`ipsum command not found`

*Disclaimer: i'm not asking to code for me or debug my code (it's sad i really have to specify this)*

Comment: Do not parse json with sed. Use `jq`. Whole your post seems to be some misunderstanding how quotation works in shell - no, double escaping the _value_ does not change anything. To escape a value later to be sourced, use `printf "%q" "$a"`. But I fail to see the purpose - just `LOCK=$(cat file.json)`, what's the point of writing it to a file? `I need to avoid command execution during the sourcing tho` why? `create conf file` what for?

Comment: The misunderstandings reflected in this code are the same ones behind [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @KamilCuk I sure had a misunderstanding on how quotation works: i tought that `" 
' ' "` was equal to `' " " '`. But I don't need to parse anything, i need to use it as it is, i don't really care what's inside.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wow, that's useful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any better way?

If you *want to* output the value to the file to be sourced later, whatever the variable value, I like to use `declare -p`.

```
lock=$(cat myjson.json)
declare -p lock >> file_to_be_sourced.sh
```

`declare` is specific to Bash, and it will always output a properly quoted string that can be sourced later. Another way is to use `printf "%q"`.

> Do you have any idea of what's going on?

`"s/'/\\\'/g"` part is wrong. If you start with `'` quotes, you have replace `'` with `'\''`. `\` is literal when inside `'` quotes. And remove the `s/"/\\"/g` part - just keep inside `'` quotes. The difference is cool to observe when using `/bin/printf` which is from coreutils vs `printf` as bash builtin - they use different quoting "style":

```
$ var="a\"b'c"
$ echo "$var"
a"b'c
$ printf "%q\n" "$var"
a\"b\'c
$ /bin/printf "%q\n" "$var"
'a"b'\''c'
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="a\"b'c"
```

> If what i'm asking is not possible, is there any other way to use a file as a string variable store?

If it's a "store" with many strings, could be you could use an associative array.

```
declare -A mapvar
mapvar["abc"]=$(< file1.json)
mapvar["def"]=$(< file2.json)
declare -p mapvar > file_to_be_sourced.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally got to a solution.
Apparently if you `echo "Something='$a'"` it does't matter if you have single, double, triple, escaped or whatever quotes inside that variable: he just doesn't care and use the double ones.
For example in my case he just ignored the outermost `'` and considered everything else as a command

My solution was very easily to:

```
echo "Something:\"$a\""
```

And now it's treated as an actual string.
I'm pretty confused about why, but that's probably caused by how bash works with quotes

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as stated in the question I just need to store the text of the json file in a variable. No need to do operations on the objects, see this more like a backup of a json, you don't want to know the value of `foo.bar.foobar.barfoo[12312]`, you just want whatever is inside the json file copied exactly as it is

Comment: If you have bash 5.0 or later, `echo "variable=${variable@Q}"` will generate an assignment that's correctly quoted for reuse. If you don't, `printf 'variable=%q\n' "$variable"`. In no circumstances is it appropriate to use `sed` to change quotes around.

Comment: Also, jq can generate shell commands. Try for example `jq -r '"var=\(. | tojson | @sh)"' <in.json` -- if its output is sourced, it will generate a shell variable `var` with the content of `in.json`.